# I want to show my csv data row by row consequently in a modal box by clicking button through mapping in react

Tags: reactjs, csv, modal-dialog, edit

I can read CSV data thru table & I want to show that data by individual row in a modal box by onClick or onDoubleClick function in react. I can't get it how to do it. Any kind of help would be appreciable. I am new to reactjs

```
render() {
        const {data, header} = this.props;
        const rows = [...data.split("\n")];
        const contentRows = header ? rows.slice(1,rows.length) : rows;

return (
            <div>
                 <Table>
                    {header && (
                        <TableHeader>
                            <TableRow>
                                {this.rowParser(rows[0]).map((value, index) => (
                                    <TableHeaderColumn key={index}>{value}</TableHeaderColumn>
                                ))}
                            </TableRow>
                        </TableHeader>
                    )}
            <TableBody displayRowCheckbox={false}>
                        {contentRows.map((row, index) => (

                            <TableRow key={index}>
                                {this.rowParser(row).map((value, index) => (
                                    <TableRowColumn key={index} data={value}>{value}
 </TableRowColumn>
                                ))}
                        <button type="button" id={index} onClick={this.handleClickOpen}>Edit</button>
                            </TableRow>
```

I want header and individual row of csv table comes up in a modal box by clicking button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to store the rowContents into this.state, then when click on button, retrieve back the rowData using this.state.rowContents[i]

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props)
   const {data, header} = this.props;
   const rows = [...data.split("\n")];
   const contentRows = header ? rows.slice(1,rows.length) : rows;
   this.state = {
     header: header,
     contentRows: contentRows,
   }
}

componentDidMount() {

}

handleClickOpen(rowIndex) {
   // Do whatever you want with the row data
   const rowData = this.state.contentsRow[rowIndex]
   console.log(rowData)
}

render() {
   // other stuff here
   {
     contentRows.map((row, rowIndex) => (
       <TableRow key={rowIndex}> 
        {
          this.rowParser(row).map((value, colIndex) => ( 
            <TableRowColumn key={colIndex} data={value}>
              {value} 
            </TableRowColumn>
          ))
        }
        <button type="button" id ={rowIndex}
          onClick={() => this.handleClickOpen(rowIndex)}>
           Edit
         </button>
      </TableRow>
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but it's not working. Thank you for your support

Comment: hey man it's working doing some modify thru your code thnx a ton man.